# Find $c$ in the moment generating function $c(3+4e^{2s}+2e^{3s})/(3-e^s)$

Tags: probability

Is there a way to find constant c in the moment generating function  $M_Y(s)=c(3+4e^{2s}+2e^{3s})/(3-e^s)$? Just like the common way to find the constant in pdf is let the cdf equal to 1. The original question is to find $Var(Y)$. Or should I just deal c as a constant?

Comment: You need $M_Y(0)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the moment generating function is defined as $$M_Y(s)=\Bbb E[e^{sY}]$$so this means that $M_Y(0)=1$. Sub $s=0$ into your formula for $M_Y(s)$, and set this equal to $1$ to obtain $c$.